# glfw get monitor width/height

Tags: c++, opengl, window, glfw

I am new to OpenGL, glfw in particular, and was wondering if it is possible to retrieve the preferred monitor's width/height (in C/C++)? e.g. something like: `unsigned int width = glfwGetMonitorWidth(), height = glfwGetMonitorHeight();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the monitor size in pixels - you must be looking for [glfwGetVideoMode](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__monitor.html#gafc1bb972a921ad5b3bd5d63a95fc2d52)

If you need the physical monitor size (in millimeters) - there is [glfwGetMonitorPhysicalSize](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/monitor_guide.html#monitor_size)

Comment: I understand how ```glfwGetMonitorPhysicalSize``` works, but what exactly does ```glfwGetVideoMode``` return and how do I get the width and height from it?

Comment: It returns the pointer on `struct GLFWvidmode` that has fields `width` and `height`

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example, as is required for answers on this website.